# How to copy a file from Windows to AS/400 IFS using cmd?

Tags: vba, copy, cmd, ibm-midrange

Suppose I want to copy a file from a Windows local directory (not on a server) to the AS/400 IFS, how to achieve this using cmd? I know there are other ways like hard drive mapping or iSeries Navigator but the aim here is to use VBA to execute such command so that when someone click a button the target file will be duplicated in the IFS. I tried to use copy command in cmd directly but it failed because the user profile and password were not supplied. So is it possible to achieve this using command in cmd? How? It is acceptable if during the process a window pops up to ask me to fill in user name and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options with VBA are:

- Upload to the IFS via FTP.
- Upload to the IFS via SMB ([iSeries Netserver](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahl%2Frzahlusergoal.htm)).
- Upload to the database and copy to the IFS using [Client] Access automation.

---

## FTP Example

You can create an ftp script file and execute it.  Here's how I usually do it with a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo open AS400_HOSTNAME > ftp.cmd
echo user AS400_USERNAME AS400_PASSWORD >> ftp.cmd
echo ascii >> ftp.cmd
echo cd AS400_PATH >> ftp.cmd
echo put PC_FILENAME AS400_FILENAME >> ftp.cmd
echo quit >> ftp.cmd
ftp.exe -n -s:ftp.cmd
```

## NetServer Example

You can force a username and password when mapping a drive to the iSeries Netserver:

```
NET USE Z: \\as400\share /USER:username password
COPY FILE.TXT Z:\DIR
NET USE Z: /DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1
Dim strCmdArg As String = "/c NET USE P: \\host.domain.com\root\home\user /user:host.domain.com\user password"
Dim strCmdDel As String = "/c NET USE /DELETE P:"
Dim strLocalFile As String = "\\windowsserver\share\folder\"
Dim strRemoteFile As String = "P:\"
Dim boolOverwrite As Boolean = True
Dim job As Process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdArg)
Dim endjob As Process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdDel)

Sub Main()
    Try
        job.Start()
        job.Dispose()
        job.Close()
        FileSystem.CopyDirectory(strLocalFile, strRemoteFile, boolOverwrite)
        endjob.Start()
        endjob.Dispose()
        endjob.Close()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.StackTrace.ToString)
        endjob.Start()
        endjob.Dispose()
        endjob.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```